# Update Only Time in Laravel Eloquent Model Field DateTime

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to update a datetime field in my database, by only changing the Time and not the date, is this possible in laravel using models ?

My researches driven me to a solution using Query method, but not using Models.

For example :
Event = ["start" => "22-22-2003 12:14:00"] All I need is adding few hours, WITHOUT editing the date.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do you want to change just one model (row) or a set models (rows)? Show an example of what exactly do you want to do with the datetime values.

Comment: @peterm, yup just added an exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```php
$event = Event::find($id);

$event->start = $event->start->addHours(2);
$event->save();
```

This assumes that your `start` attribute is being casted to a [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com) instance, which is usually done by adding it to the `$dates` property of your model.

```php
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'start',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Undifnied method addHours

Comment: This means that your attribute is not casted to a Carbon instance. You can either make it so (see updated answer) or instantiate it explicitly yourself.

Comment: A part of this is correct, but I don't know how much hours to add, I just need to update the time by a given another time

Comment: I found out how to do it (split and so on) and I'm selecting this as the right answer. thank you !